# Framework 7 V2: How to close popup overlay in android device back button

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I am using framework 7 version 2, using overlay popup for showing menus, after i open the menu popup if i press the device back button popup is not closing.

please help on this.

Regards
Girija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manual handle 'backbutton' event:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackButton, false);
}

function onBackButton() {
   if ($('.modal-in').length > 0) {
        app.dialog.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or switch to framework7 V4 and use Routable Modals that have built-in support for forward and backward navigation: https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#routable-modals

Comment: HI.. app.dialog.close() not working. how to close popup overlay in framework7 V2